# postfix " Relay access denied" for all incoming emails

Tags: postfix

Please help to figure out what i did wrong in postfix config. When i try to send test email from gmail i get this error in /var/syslog

```
Oct 24 16:20:57 DBHOST postfix/smtpd[31511]: connect from mail-vc0-f180.google.com[209.85.220.180]
Oct 24 16:20:58 DBHOST postfix/smtpd[31511]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-vc0-f180.google.com[209.85.220.180]: 554 5.7.1 <hostmaster@g01.server.com>: Relay access denied; from=<gregory.chalenko@gmail.com> to=<hostmaster@g01.server.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-vc0-f180.google.com>
Oct 24 16:20:58 DBHOST postfix/smtpd[31511]: disconnect from mail-vc0-f180.google.com[209.85.220.180]


**@ postconf -n**
    alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
    alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
    append_dot_mydomain = no
    biff = no
    bounce_queue_lifetime = 2h
    config_directory = /etc/postfix
    *inet_interfaces = IP:1 IP:2 localhost*
    mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
    mailbox_size_limit = 0
    milter_default_action = accept
    milter_protocol = 2
    mydestination = $mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain
    myhostname = server.com
    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 85.254.49.128 85.254.49.129
    myorigin = /etc/mailname
    non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
    readme_directory = no
    recipient_delimiter = +
    relayhost =
    smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
    smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
    smtpd_helo_required = yes
    smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
    smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_recipient        reject_non_fqdn_sender  reject_unknown_sender_domain    reject_unknown_recipient_domain permit_mynetworks       reject_unauth_destination  check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/roleaccount_exceptions  reject_non_fqdn_hostname        reject_invalid_hostname check_sender_mx_access cidr:/etc/postfix/bogus_mx       permit
    smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
    smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
    smtpd_use_tls = yes
    transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
    virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases

**cat/etc/postfix/transport**
bounce@g01.server.com   bouncepipe
bounce@g02.server.com   bouncepipe
bounce@server.com   bouncepipe

**cat /etc/postfix/virtual_aliases**
@g01.server.com         root@g01.server.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set

`mydomain=g01.server.com`

Can you post output of domainname command on that server?

Comment: thanks for reply. the output of **domainname** was (none).i set mydomain variable in main.conf now i get another type of errors, but it`s okay hope will figure out whats wrong


Oct 24 17:01:46 DBHOST postfix/pipe[1049]: fatal: user= command-line attribute specifies root privileges
Oct 24 17:01:47 DBHOST postfix/qmgr[1028]: warning: private/bouncepipe socket: malformed response
 :)